# Aurelia replaces # hash with / for dynamically created anchor tags

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, aurelia

I'm trying to implement [BootStrap Scroll Spy](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_scrollspy.asp) in my Aurelia app. I have the following dynamically created anchor tags:

```
<div class="nav-link au-animate" repeat.for="section of variant.sections">
    <a href="#${section.id}">${section.title}</a>
</div>
```

But the anchor tags don't work and I get the following console error:

```
Route not found: /${section.id}
```

How can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your `href`. You are not closing the `{`. So, your anchor is being generated as is, without the `section.id` value binding. Change it to:

```
<div class="nav-link au-animate" repeat.for="section of variant.sections">
    <a href="#${section.id}">${section.title}</a>
</div>
```

I have added a [gist](https://gist.run/?id=0bc9c9e075c14d984b0fd4e57482c288).

([Embedded result window without nav collapse](https://gist.run/embed.html?id=0bc9c9e075c14d984b0fd4e57482c288))

Comment: Sorry, my bad, that was actually a typo in my question.

Comment: @Viqas okay. But the gist still works. Have you configured your router like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/38668108/3082296 and http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/router/latest/router-configuration/2

Comment: Problem is it only works when you're on `/`. When on any other URL you will be redirected to `/` plus `#the-hash-you-linked-to`

Comment: @powerbuoy I have the same issue: it redirects to the root page `/#hashHere`. It doesn't keep the current URL